# Maximize a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

How to maximize or find a condition for maximum of the following function

$$ f(x,y,z,w) = a(x+y)e^{-a(x+y+z+w)} $$

I tried to apply the second derivative test and obtain the following Hessian matrix

$$ H_f = ae^{-a(x+y+z+w)} \begin{bmatrix} a(x+y)-2 & a(x+y)-2 & a(x+y)-1 & a(x+y)-1 \\
a(x+y)-2 & a(x+y)-2 & a(x+y)-1 & a(x+y)-1  \\
a(x+y)-1 & a(x+y)-1 & x+y& x+y \\
a(x+y)-1 & a(x+y)-1 & x+y& x+y
\end{bmatrix}$$

But apparently, $H_f$ is [not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) positive definite as each block has an eigenvalue of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x+y,z+w)=f(x,y,z,w)=a(x+y)e^{-a(x+y+z+w)}$. then $g(s,t)=ase^{-a(s+t)}$.

Then Hessian of $g$ comes with...
$$ H_g = a^2e^{-a(s+t)} \begin{bmatrix} as-2 & as-1 \\
as-1 & as 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then the Hessian determinant is $-a^4e^{-2a(s+t)}<0$.